# grid getting cut in half when loaded with half off screen

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a listview, In the list view you can click on an order number and it will pop up a grid to edit details about the order!

This grid it pops up is Drag-able via this code(tt is a translatetransform):

```
     Point m_start;
    Vector m_startOffset;

    private void Grid_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        m_start = e.GetPosition(mainWindow);
        m_startOffset = new Vector(tt.X, tt.Y);
        gridShippingInstructionsForOrder.CaptureMouse();
    }

    private void Grid_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (gridShippingInstructionsForOrder.IsMouseCaptured)
        {
            Vector offset = Point.Subtract(e.GetPosition(mainWindow), m_start);

            tt.X = m_startOffset.X + offset.X;
            tt.Y = m_startOffset.Y + offset.Y;
        }
    }

    private void Grid_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        gridShippingInstructionsForOrder.ReleaseMouseCapture();
    }
```

Now the problem is when you click an order at the bottom of the screen it pops up the grid half off of the screen, and when you drag it on to the screen it's chopped in half! (Even after dragging it back into the middle of the screen)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is `tt`? Is this Grid in a Canvas?

Comment: tt is a translate transform assosiated with the grid, No it's not in a canvas, it is however in a viewbox

Comment: The code you provided looks okay, issue must be somewhere else.

Comment: What if you translate the ViewBox which is container of your Grid ?